# What does "much to the displeasure of" mean?

Tags: definition

> But he stayed put, and so did Biron, much to the displeasure of the crowd.

Did he and Biron stay put because of the crowd's displeasure or the crowd was displeasured by Biron and him to stay put?

> After pushing into the Nashville zone early, the Rangers retreated, much to the displeasure of the fans.

Did the Rangers retreat because of the fans' displeasure or the fans were displeasured by Rangers' retreat?

> The Real president sacked Ancelotti last summer, much to the displeasure of many of the senior players in the squad.

Did the Real president sacked Ancelotti due to displeasure of many of the senior players or many of the senior players were displeasured by the Real president's sacking of Ancelotti?

---

**Source:** https://ludwig.guru/s/much+to+the+displeasure

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *much to the displeasure of X* means that X was very ***displeased by*** (angry at) what the subject of the sentence had done.

So, in your first example, the crowd was displeased that he and Biron were staying put (remaining where they were).